# iOS - managing trusted roots on an SSL connection

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ssl, x509

By adding to the kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings dictionary the usual kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot, etc - I can make server & client authentication work.

However I fail to see how I can get this more fine grained; i.e.

1. detect a cert of server/CA never seen - and escalate acceptance up to the user.
2. validate a cert of the server I am connected to against a narrow trust list (e.g. the cert learned about during a previous connect).

I.e. what I am looking for is 1) something like the SSLSetTrustedRoots() on MacOSX and 2) something like the error/domain callbacks in kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL (e.g. errSSLPeerCertUnknown) - none which seems defined/accesible on the ipad/iphone 4.2.1.

Or am I missing something ? Or do I need to do something explicit on the callback ? Examples appreciated (the AdvancedURLConnections example is not quite applicable - I have a raw (IRC) socket).

Thanks,

Dw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain to kBooleanFalse and manually verify the cert with the  APIs.

Specifically, use

```
SecTrustCreateWithCertificates
```

with the certificates you get from

```
CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates);
```

Then, you can use

```
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates
```

and finally call

```
SecTrustEvaluate
```

Comment: Heath - do you have any sample code? The functions mentioned do not have an accompanying Apple sample (on their site), and Graham Lee does not cover in Coca Application Security. I feel like Alice tumbling down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Check out my blog post on the subject.  It covers some of these issues.
https://blog.asolutions.com/2011/02/using-tls-with-self-signed-certificates-or-custom-root-certificates-in-ios/